# SQL syntax check th

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following query in MySQL

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER param after insert on wpkp_param_transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test(trId,ccNumber) VALUES(new.trId, new.ccNumber)
END
```

Which results in this error...

> MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 5

I cannot work out what is causing this error?

Comment: delimiter is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER param 
AFTER INSERT ON wpkp_param_transaction 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO test(trId,ccNumber) 
    VALUES(new.trId, new.ccNumber);
```

1. The source of your problem is forgotten `DELIMITER` re-assign and lost `;` at the end of INSERT statement.
2. The trigger code contains one statement only - in this case neither BEGIN-END nor delimiter reassigning are needed.